# showing and hide divs using jQuery and adding/clearing div content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a group of radio buttons that control a group of div containers.  When a radio button is clicked, it opens the appropriate div and hides all the other ones.

The jQuery function does this by controlling the CSS.

Inside the jQuery function, I am also adding HTML from another div.

The issue is, when switching through the radio buttons, is that some of the div content will become duplicated.  And if I click off, then click back on, it will duplicate again.

I was hoping there was a better way of doing this so that it looks cleaner and also doesn't duplicate HTML content.

Here is my code:

```
    var questionCounter = 1;
var parentId;
var answerHTML;
$(function () {
    $('[name=RadioButtonClicked]').click(function () {
        $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).fadeIn().siblings('div').hide();
        questionCounter = 1;

        var RadioButtonClicked = $(this).attr("id");

        var newTextBoxDiv = $("<div>").attr("id");

        if (RadioButtonClicked == 'radBoxA') {
            parentId = "#BoxA";
            $("#BoxA").css("display", "block");
            $("#BoxB").css("display", "none");
            $("#BoxC").css("display", "none");
            $("#BoxD").css("display", "none");
            answerHTML = $("#BoxA_Answer").html();

        } else if (RadioButtonClicked == 'radBoxB') {
            parentId ="#BoxB";
            $("#BoxB").css("display", "block");
            $("#BoxA").css("display", "none");
            $("#BoxC").css("display", "none");
            $("#BoxD").css("display", "none");
            answerHTML = $("#BoxB_Answer").html();

        } else if (RadioButtonClicked == "radBoxC") {
            parentId = "#BoxC";
            $("#BoxC").css("display", "block");
            $("#BoxB").css("display", "none");
            $("#BoxA").css("display", "none");
            $("#BoxD").css("display", "none");
            answerHTML = $("#BoxC_Answer").html();

        } else {
            parentId = "#BoxD";
            $("#BoxD").css("display", "block");
            $("#BoxB").css("display", "none");
            $("#BoxA").css("display", "none");
            $("#BoxC").css("display", "none");
            answerHTML = $("#BoxD_Answer").html();
        }
        newTextBoxDiv.remove();
        newTextBoxDiv.html(answerHTML);
        $(parentId).append(newTextBoxDiv);
        questionCounter++;

    })
    //.filter(':checked').click();
});
```

Thanks

Comment: could you post your html? Or better yet, a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `html()` instead of `append()`

> append : inserts the content, to the end of specified elements
>
> html: inserts it to the specified element (replaces the entire content inside the specified element)

replace this

```
$(parentId).append(newTextBoxDiv);
```

with

```
$(parentId).html(newTextBoxDiv);
```